# Want to set default value of Input field via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a form and making input field to read only using JavaScript. I change the default color for read only attribute. I want to display a default value when the field is `readonly` i-e "NIL"

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female <br/>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="20">
Hobbies:<input type="text" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" size="20"><br/>
Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="20"><br/>
```

JS

```
$("input[name='sex']").change(function() {
if($(this).val() == "female") {
    $("#age,#phone").attr("disabled", true).css("background-color","#0F0");
} else if($(this).val() == "male") {
    $("#age,#phone").attr("disabled", false).css("background-color","#FFF");;
}
});
```

I want add the default value "Nil" if the field is `readonly`. Kindly guide me how to add this property to my script.

Comment: @Ashish You should stop asking people to see your answers.. what else do you think they are doing here except seeing answers?!

Comment: @Lipis Thanks for your valuable comment. I take a note of it.

Comment: The title of the question is about setting default value, its text refers to setting color for `readonly` elements, but the code included has no such elements and no attempt at setting content color, only background color. Please edit your question to be consistent and clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("input[name='sex']").change(function() {
if($(this).val() == "female") {
     $("#age,#phone").val('Nil');
    $("#age,#phone").attr("disabled", true).css("background-color","#0F0");

} else if($(this).val() == "male") {
    $("#age,#phone").val('');
    $("#age,#phone").attr("disabled", false).css("background-color","#FFF");
}
});
```

Working Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/hpee0w0d/

Comment: I think we should stop using JSFiddle links.. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan based on the code provided in your question, `#age` and `#phone` **aren't** `readonly`. This answer does not answer the question you've asked.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly In the code provided in question 'disable' attribute is used, so in my answer. I believe the objective as it is evident from question was to set a default value 'Nil' to #age and #phone fields that change into not-editable fields once radio button (that holds the value 'female') is clicked. Non-editable fields are read-only. 'read-only' and 'disabled' are used to make fields non-editable.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Difference between 'readonly' and 'disabled' attributes is - elements with 'readonly' attribute can receive focus, and are sent on submit whereas 'disabled' element can't receive focus and can not be sent on submit. My answer corresponds to the code given in the question.

Comment: @Ashish `readonly` and `disabled` are completely different attributes, so my point still stands. You've answered what the user wanted, but you've not answered the question given.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes James, 'readonly' and 'disabled' are different though not completely since these have one similarity which is - both can be used to make fields non-editable. Difference between these two I have posted in my previous comment. Yes, I have answered what the questioner wanted based on the code provided in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To give *all* elements with a `readonly` attribute a value of "Nil", you can use the `[readonly]` [**attribute selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this:

```js
$('[readonly]').val('Nil');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" />
```

---

You may want to first ensure that your element's value is empty before doing this. To do that, you'd introduce a [**`filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this:

```js
$('[readonly]').filter(function() {
  return this.value == ""
}).val('Nil');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" value="Has a value" readonly />
<input type="text" />
```